# Change background color of a parent div when child input checked

Tags: html, css

Here's the code. What I need is to change the background color of .register-switch when "Female" input is checked.
I tried:

```
input[value="Female"]:checked + .register-switch { 
  background: red;
}
```

but it doesn't work. Is it possible to achieve the desired effect without using JavaScript?

```css
.register-switch {
  height: 32px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 4px;
  background: lightblue;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.register-switch-input {
  display: none;
}
.register-switch-label {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  line-height: 32px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.register-switch-input:checked + .register-switch-label {
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #666;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe, #eeeeee);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe, #eeeeee);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe, #eeeeee);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fefefe, #eeeeee);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="register-switch">
  <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Male" id="sex-m" class="register-switch-input" checked>
  <label for="sex-m" class="register-switch-label">Male</label>
  <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Female" id="sex-f" class="register-switch-input">
  <label for="sex-f" class="register-switch-label">Female</label>
</div>
```

Comment: There's no parent selector in CSS (yet) so you'd have to either change the HTML/CSS or use JS.

Comment: I am afraid the answer is no

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try something like this.

Instead of applying a background color to the parent element,create an `:after` `pseudo-element` with 100% height and width and apply the background to the `after` later this can be accessed using the `+` selector.make sure to set `position:relative` on the parent element(`.register-switch`)

```css
.register-switch {
  height: 32px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 4px;
  position:relative;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.register-switch-input {
  display: none;
}
.register-switch-label {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  line-height: 32px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.register-switch-label:after{
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:lightblue;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  z-index:-1;
  }
.register-switch-input:checked + .register-switch-label:after{
  background:tomato;
  }
.register-switch-input:checked + .register-switch-label {
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #666;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe, #eeeeee);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe, #eeeeee);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe, #eeeeee);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fefefe, #eeeeee);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="register-switch">
  <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Male" id="sex-m" class="register-switch-input" checked>
  <label for="sex-m" class="register-switch-label">Male</label>
  <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Female" id="sex-f" class="register-switch-input">
  <label for="sex-f" class="register-switch-label">Female</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Pangloss Glad you liked it

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to select the parent element of the radio input and add/remove a class when that input is changed.

```html
<div class="register-switch">
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Male" id="sex-m" class="register-switch-input" checked>
    <label for="sex-m" class="register-switch-label">Male</label>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Female" id="sex-f" class="register-switch-input">
    <label for="sex-f" class="register-switch-label">Female</label>
</div>
```

```css
.clicked {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```js
$( '.register-switch-input' ).on( 'change', function() {
    $this = $( this );
    $this.parent().addClass( 'clicked' );
} );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yfh301od/

Comment: The OP said _"without using JavaScript"_, let alone adding jQuery to the mix.

Comment: Whoops! Scanned too quick and missed the _"without"_ part. Then again, after re-reading OP asked _"if possible without using JavaScript."_ If a CSS only solution wasn't possible, then a JS answer would be acceptable _imho_. Though Akshay has proven that JS is not required for an solution to this problem.